# YARN Schedulers - Fair Scheduler - Running Jobs specifying Queue

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

How do we assign Jobs to specifying Queue when we have multiple queues. I'm using Yarn hadoop with AWS EMR

Comment: Running jobs of what kind? Spark, for example, has a queue option during submission

Answer (score 0):

On AWS EMR you can create a cluster with Spark installed and set spark.scheduler.mode , using the following command, which references a file, myConfig.json stored in Amazon S3.

```
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.36.0 --applications Name=Spark \
--instance-type m5.xlarge --instance-count 2 --service-role EMR_DefaultRole --ec2-attributes InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole --configurations https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfolder/myConfig.json
```

myConfig.json:

```
[
    {
      "Classification": "spark-defaults",
      "Properties": {
        "spark.scheduler.mode": "FAIR"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Or you can specify which scheduler to use when initializing the job resource with the following parameters

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
sparkConf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
...
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. really appreciate it. currently i'm using hadoop. i found a way to do this hive -f "query.hql"  -hiveconf tez.queue.name=qa                               *qa is one of my queue names. i'm executing this in a shell script. *query.hql is my hive query. it is in another file.